# jQuery "slime menu" - pixel perfect rounding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform, rounding

I've successfully programmed my jQuery slime menu, and now it works beautiful. My only problem is that I move the arrow and the ending circle (the icon) of the slime separately, so if you move the cursor too away from the starting point, it will not connect to the slime precisely. It must be a rounding issue. Here's an image of what I'm talking about:

[image]

And here's the fiddle I'm working on:
http://jsfiddle.net/41Lcj653/4/

EDIT (Working): http://jsfiddle.net/41Lcj653/7/

Can anyone help with this issue? I use CSS  transformations, and JS for update the CSS rules in each step.

The JS part of the code:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).mousemove(function(e){
        moveslime(e);
    });
});

function moveslime(e){
    var rad  = $('.arrow').height() / 2;
    var ofs  = $('.arrow').offset();
    var mPos = {x: e.pageX-25-rad, y: e.pageY-25-rad};
    var dir  = Math.round( -(Math.atan2(mPos.x, mPos.y)) / (Math.PI/180) );
    $('.arrow').css('transform','rotate('+dir+'deg)');
    $('.arrow').css('border-width','0 25px '+pdist(0, 0, mPos.x, mPos.y)+'px 25px');
    $('.bubble').css('left', mPos.x+'px').css('top', mPos.y+'px');
}

function pdist(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2)+Math.pow(y1-y2,2));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you calculate the width at the end of the arrow?

Comment: The width of the arrow has a fixed 50px ( border-width: { 0px 25px %VARIABLE% 25px; } ) 25x2 = 50px. The following circle has a fixed 50px width too. I think the problem is that the angle of the arrow was rounded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you see this 'not precisely connected' is that rotate goes in 360 steps (the 360 degrees of a circle). when you are near the center the effect can be neglected, but the more you get away from the center (increasing circle circumference!) the visible gap between the degrees increases.
Maybe try this with svg?

actually you can use float numbers a degree .. so dont round the deg!

https://jsfiddle.net/41Lcj653/5/

```
// without math.round
 var dir  = -(Math.atan2(mPos.x, mPos.y)) / (Math.PI/180);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some jQuery method like height rounds decimals. You could try this:

```
$(".arrow")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height
```

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect